# How did Kylo Ren's helmet lock up?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology, kylo-ren

In *The Force Awakens*, prior to interrogating Rey, Kylo Ren removed his helmet. Before he took it off, a small casing in the front of the mask moved upwards.

[image]

Was this some kind of a locking mechanism, or what was the purpose of this function? If it got stuck somehow, would it have been impossible for Kylo to remove the mask?

Comment: If it got stuck, I guess he’d have to use the power of the dark side to remove his helmet.

Comment: @Adamant  - Or WD-40.

Comment: It's just #RuleOfCool..

Comment: Adam Driver has a fairly [big nose](http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Observer/Pix/pictures/2015/3/25/1427307462885/Adam-Driver-feature-009.jpg), so the breathing apparatus in the helmet has to be able to be moved out of the way so that the helmet can come off.

Comment: An unnecessarily fancy variant of a chin strap, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

**Through a face mask hinged mechanism driven by servomotors.**

According to the Canon reference book *Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary*, the small casing, you mention, that moves upward in the front of Kylo Ren's helmet, is a face mask connected to the helmet via articulated arms driven by servomotors; a hinged mechanism sealed the mask to the helmet. Although Kylo wore the helmet to make himself appear more intimidating, on rare occasions he would remove it via the servomotors to stare down his opponents with unrestrained malice in his eyes.

[image: Image from Star Wars The Force Awakens The Visual Dictionary]

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren%27s_helmet